# Beginner Python: save output file as argv input filename

Tags: python, filenames, argv

I want to save my generated plot with the same name as the input file. The input is through the command line, so I'm not really sure how to do it.

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import matplotlib
matplotlib.use('Agg')
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from numpy import arange,array,ones#,random,linalg
from pylab import plot,show
from scipy import stats
from sys import argv

a = argv[1]
b = argv[2]

list1 = open(a)
list2 = open(b)

xi = list1.read().splitlines()
filter(None,xi)

y = list2.read().splitlines()
filter(None,y)

xi = [float(xk) for xk in xi]
y = [float(yk) for yk in y]

slope, intercept, r_value, p_value, std_err = stats.linregress(xi,y)

print 'r value', r_value

line = slope*xi+intercept
plot(xi,line,'r-',xi,y,'o')
plt.savefig('a')
```

My input is number001.txt and I would like the output to be number001.png.

Thanks!!

Comment: plt.savefig(argv[1][:-4]+'.png') # I'm assuming the input is in argv[1]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. Get input file name by the `sys.argv`
2. Use same name with different extension to save result.

Simple example to get input file name and use same file name to save output.

e.g.

```
import sys

if __name__=="__main__":
    print "argument:", sys.argv  

    inputfile = sys.argv[1]
    print "inputfile:", inputfile

    outputfile = inputfile.split(".")[0] + "__output.txt"

    print "outputfile:", outputfile

    with open(outputfile, "wb" ) as fp:
        fp.write("some content")
```

output:

```
vivek@vivek:~/Desktop/stackoverflow$ python 25.py test.txt
argument: ['25.py', 'test.txt']
inputfile: test.txt
outputfile: test__output.txt
```

---

also `os` module have path split method.

e.g.

```
>>> import os
>>> os.path.splitext("input.txt")
('input', '.txt')
```

Comment: The split solution is more pythonic than mine, +1